# Configuration for ASPState database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, tempdb

Persistent ASP Session store can reside in either "tempdb" or "aspstate" database in SQL Server 2005. The sqlConnectionString parameter, in sessionState doesn't specify this (example below). How is this resolved?

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Server=mysqlserver;Integrated Security=SSPI;" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think within sqlConnectionString you need another key/value pair:

```
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
```

Check out this page [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

If that doesn't work then it might be:

```
Database=myDataBase;
```

But I think you need the first example.

Comment: Catalog is not required when specifying the database for session state.